# why swashbuckle not showing request schema link in my .net 6 web api project?

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, swashbuckle.examples

I use swashbuckle to generate a swagger page. In response part, I can see schema link:
[image]

But at the request part, I only see example, but not schema link:
[image]

This is my c# code

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [Route("v2.0/Data")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(FundInfoSimpleResponse))]  
        [SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(FundInfoSimpleRequestV11), typeof(FundInfoSimpleRequestExampleV11))]
        [SwaggerResponseExample((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(FundInfoSimpleResponseExample))]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessageResult> FundInfoSimple([FromBody] FundInfoSimpleRequestV11 request)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The schema is only displayed when you are not in `Try it out` mode. By the way, one can change the default behavior by using:

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});
```